# Combination of two Binomial Draws Or "Group and sum matrix by value"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider two urns, `E` and `U`. There are holy grails and crappy grails in each of these. Denote the holy ones with `H`.

Say we draw out of both urns, `xe` times out of `E`, and `xu` times out of `U` - how many holy grails are we going to find? This is easily solvable for any pair (`xe`, `xu`). But I'd like to do this for grids of draws out of `xe` and `xu`.

1. What is the most efficient way to do this in Python using standard packages?

---

Here is my approach.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
binomial = stats.binom.pmf
# define the grids of E, U to search
numberOfE = np.arange(3)
numberOfHolyE = np.arange(3)
numberOfU = np.arange(5)
numberOfHolyU = np.arange(5)

# mesh it
E, U, EH, UH = np.meshgrid(numberOfE, numberOfU, numberOfHolyE, numberOfHolyU, indexing='ij')

# independent draws from both urns. Probabilities are 0.9 and 0.1
drawsE = binomial(EH, E, 0.9)
drawsU = binomial(UH, U, 0.1)

# joint probability of being at a specific grid point
prob = drawsE * drawsU
totalHigh = EH + UH
```

This is how far I've come:

```
In [77]: prob[1,1,:]
Out[77]: 
array([[ 0.09,  0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.81,  0.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])

In [78]: totalHigh[1,1,:]
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

*I think, that*, these matrices mean the following:

Take a look at where totalHigh has value `1`: if I draw one time from both urns, I have a 0.81 probability of drawing one high from `E` and zero from `U`, and `0.01` the other way around. That means, the total probability of drawing one guy conditional on drawing once from both urns is `0.82`.

Which brings me to my second question:

2. Conditional on doing it this way, How do I sum up these probabilities efficiently, conditional on the first two dimensions? I effectively want to transform these 4D matrices into 3D matrices.

Comment: If someone has an idea for a better title, I'm happy to change it.